# Object in a sentence

Tags: objects

As for my knowledge, the **object** in a sentence is used to talk about the thing or person that the verb is done to or who receives the verb.

For example :

> I put the orange cat into the garden.

With this sentence, it's easy to identify the `object` which is **the orange cat** where the orange cat is the one who receives the verb.

But, how about this :

> She was so unpopular that few people visited her in the hospital when she was ill.

I was confused and unsure which one is the object. Is it **few people** or **her**? or since the verb here is `visited` so the object in the sentence is **her**?

Comment: Yes, in your first example "the orange cat" is direct object. There is no indirect object. In your second example, the object is "her". "Few people" is subject of the declarative content clause "that few people visited her in the hospital when she was ill".

Comment: You mean "As far as I know", not "As for my knowledge", something no native speaker would ever say that way.

Comment: @tchrist I thought it's correct to say so. By the way, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Leon Perhaps you’ve mixed up “to the best of my knowledge” with “as far as I know”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is a complex one: it has one independent clause (with the subject 'she') and two dependent ones (with subjects 'people' and 'she'). There's a *direct* object '**her**' in the second clause ('people visited her in the hospital': visited *whom*?).

These explanations might be useful:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/subjects-and-objects
https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/sentencestructure

Comment: I think there's a significant difference between the "indirect object" in *few people visited her **in the hospital** when she was ill* and *few people gave her **flowers** when she was ill*, in that the ***hospital*** version requires a preposition, whereas ***to give*** can be used ditransitively with two objects (one direct, the other indirect) and no prepositions.

Comment: *The garden* is not an indirect object. Rather, it is the complement of the preposition *into*. *Into the garden* is a preposition phrase (PP).

Comment: "The garden" is not an indirect object. It is complement of the prep "into". The PP "into the garden" then functions as a locative complement of "put".

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I've removed the mentioning of indirect objects (which are actually prepositional phrases here).